# How to stop "SMTP Configuration Test" email every time I send a Newsletter in DotNetNuke 5.0?

Tags: email, smtp, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

The question is in the title, every time i send out a Newsletter from DNN (Newsletter Module) the Admin gets a blank "SMTP Configuration Test" email.

How do I stop that email?

Comment: I'm glad someone else hates this as much as I do

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an easy answer to this one - what I might suggest is looking at something like mailchimp if your mail list is small or buying some module like Axiom if you have a larger list or mail more often

Comment: do you have any information on the issue itself? is this a bug or "by design"?